# webpack with less files in subfolders and images in one folder

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have large AngularJS and I try migrate from Grunt to webpack.
I can't change structure of project but with current structure I stuck on problem with loading images from less files. I think I should replace image path from relative to absolute, because webpack try loading images from subfolders(styles/components) where less files located.

It is my webpack config:

```
   config.output = {
      path: __dirname + '/app',

      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
   };
config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
  loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
});
var cssLoader = {
    test: /\.less/,

    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss!less-loader')
  };

config.module.loaders.push(cssLoader);

config.plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css')
  ];
```

And in entry file(`app/scripts/bootstrap.js`) I have:

```
import './../styles/style.less';
```

But when I try run dev server I get these errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/less-loader!./app/styles/style.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./img/arrow-up-gray.png in /Users/nucleartux/Work/projects/ondoc-angular/app/styles
 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/less-loader!./app/styles/style.less 7:174762-174796

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/less-loader!./app/styles/style.less
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.eot in /Users/nucleartux/Work/projects/ondoc-angular/app/styles
 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/less-loader!./app/styles/style.less 7:176400-176450
```

How I can fix errors without rewriting all less files?

My project structure

[image]

And part from style in `app/styles/components/commom.less`:

```
background: url(../img/arrow-down-gray.png) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the folder that holds the images (/img/arrow-up-gray.png) into resolve.root:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root

What I actually do is:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve('./static')
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not help, my config https://gist.github.com/nucleartux/b2d0e3e3abd2f8c67357